# RuntimeException - Namespace "Numbers\Bundle\NumbersBundle" does not contain any mapped entities

Tags: doctrine, symfony

To generate my Symfony Entities I have some Doctrine schemas. E.g at

```
src/Numbers/Bundle/NumbersBundle/config/doctrine/Numbers.orm.yml
```

[UPDATE: also tried this with the same problem...

```
src/Numbers/Bundle/NumbersBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Number.orm.yml ]
```

and I'm running:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities Numbers/Bundle/NumbersBundle
```

which gives

```
Generating entities for namespace "Numbers\Bundle\NumbersBundle"

[RuntimeException]                                                              
Namespace "Numbers\Bundle\NumbersBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

If it helps the YML is:

```
# src/Numbers/Bundle/NumbersBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Numbers.orm.yml
Numbers\Bundle\NumbersBundle\Entity\Number:
  type: entity
  table: numbers
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    value:
      type: integer
      unique: true
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      unique: true
```

Any suggestions what the problem might be or how you can debug this to see what `bin/console doctrine:generate:entities` is doing?

UPDATE

For what it's worth with `-vvv` I get this (doesn't seem to help much though):

```
php bin/console -vvv doctrine:generate:entities Numbers\Bundle\NumbersBundle
Generating entities for namespace "NumbersBundleNumbersBundle"


[RuntimeException]                                                            
Namespace "NumbersBundleNumbersBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.  


Exception trace:
 () at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Mapping/DisconnectedMetadataFactory.php:103
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Mapping\DisconnectedMetadataFactory->getNamespaceMetadata() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Command/GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand.php:109
 Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\GenerateEntitiesDoctrineCommand->execute() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:846
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:191
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:80
 Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:122
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /Users/snowcrash/numbers/bin/console:28

doctrine:generate:entities [--path PATH] [--no-backup] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <name>
```

UPDATE 2

Now with a simpler Namespace:

```
# src/NumbersBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Number.orm.yml
NumberBundle\Entity\Number:
  type: entity
  table: numbers
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    value:
      type: integer
      unique: true
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
      unique: true


php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities NumbersBundle
Generating entities for namespace "NumbersBundle"


  [RuntimeException]                                               
  Namespace "NumbersBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.
```

with the file at

```
src/NumbersBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Number.orm.yml
```

and specifying the Entity:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities NumbersBundle:Number


  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]                      
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'NumbersBundle'.
```

Comment: Try removing that ending `s` from the file name. It should be `.../NumbersBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Number.orm.yml`. And give it a try.

Comment: Tried that. Same problem. Any way of debugging this?

Comment: Does exist table `numbers` in your database really?

Comment: I tried your example and for me it worked. Seems that you have other problem. I suggest you create a new empty project and try it one more time.